# SmallRye Mutiny unable to process events asynchronously using subscription

Tags: java, quarkus, reactive-streams, mutiny, smallrye

I am developing an application that returns `Multi<String>`, I would like to make some modifications to it, so I have added some methods, but for some reason it does not enter the `next` method at all.

My other methods are working absolutely fine. Because I am able to collect it and add it to a `List`, but I want to do some execution asynchronously, so using this approach.

```
private final ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;

public void writeTo(StreamingInfo streamingInfo) {
            streamingInfo
                .getEvents()
                .runSubscriptionOn(managedExecutor)
                .subscribe()
                .withSubscriber(
                    new Subscriber < String > () {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                            System.out.println("OnSubscription Method");
                            System.out.println("ON SUBS END");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(String event) {
                            System.out.println("On Next Method");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            System.out.println("OnError Method");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            System.out.println("On Complete Method");
                        }
                    });
        }
```

I get the following output:

```
OnSubscription Method
ON SUBS END
```

Which means that your subscription is not working for some reason. If I do not add subscription and directly collect to List then everything works as expected. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the underlying Reactive Streams specification that SmallRye Mutiny implements has a built-in backpressure mechanism. The client (in your case your subscriber) needs to request the next item manually from the producer (events) otherwise, no item is sent down the reactive pipeline.

You need to save the Subscription object you receive in the onSubscribe method and call its `request(long)` method when you can process next item(s):

```
.withSubscriber(
    new Subscriber<String>() {
        private Subscription subscription;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                System.out.println("OnSubscription Method");
                System.out.println("ON SUBS END");
                subscription = s;
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String event) {
                System.out.println("On Next Method");
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("OnError Method");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("On Complete Method");
            }
        });
```

In SmallRye there is also an easier way to do this:

```
events
    .onSubscription()
        .invoke(() -> {
            System.out.println("OnSubscription Method");
            System.out.println("ON SUBS END");
        })
    .onItem()
        .invoke(event -> System.out.println("On Next Method"))
    .onFailure()
        .invoke(t -> System.out.println("OnError Method"))
    .onCompletion()
        .invoke(() -> System.out.println("On Complete Method"))
    .subscribe()
        .with(value -> {});
```